# How to read response from an authenticated api (Django) using angular4

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, mod-auth-openidc

I have tried to fetch data from an authenticated API which is developed in 
Django REST API Framework, Functionality used in the REST API(mod_auth_openidc), I need to call the same API to display the data in front end using angular4.

https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client

I have tried the above-mentioned method, but google authentication pop-up is opened correctly and the API loads in the browser window. I need to make an API call after the successful authentication.

Comment: use a [**DOMParser**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-xml bower dependency, https://github.com/johngeorgewright/angular-xml2. It also have nicely written manuals.

Comment: I try to install angular-xml bower, but it was not installed properly.